# Parsing string using regex where delimiter varies

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following strings I need to parse:

```
<!-- MOCK -->
<!--MOCK-->
<!-- MOCK:SENT;FAIL -->
<!--MOCK:SENT;SUCCESS-->
<!--MOCK:SENT; SUCCESS-->
<!--MOCK:SENT ; SUCCESS-->
<!--MOCK:SENT -->
<!-- MOCK:SENT-->
<!-- MOCK : SENT -->
<!-- MOCK: SENT -->
<!-- MOCK :SENT -->
```

Because these may be entered by a person I want to provide, within reason, support for various spacing.

I've gotten as far as the following regular expression.

```
<!-- *(?<mode>.*?(?=[ \-:])).*: *(?<responses>.*?(?= *-->))
```

This works for all of the above test strings except the first two. In those first two cases the "mode" group comes back empty, which I don't understand because I thought the `?<mode>.*?(?=[ \-:])` would collect all characters until it came upon a space, dash, or colon. If I change `.*: *` in the middle to `.*:? *` then I get all the "mode" values but I lose all of my "responses" values.

My test code is in .NET Fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/HzIXch), but here it is for completeness.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<!-- *(?<mode>.*?(?=[ \-:])).*: *(?<responses>.*?(?= *-->))");
var values = new[] {
    "<!-- MOCK -->", 
    "<!--MOCK-->", 
    "<!-- MOCK:SENT;FAIL -->", 
    "<!--MOCK:SENT;SUCCESS-->", 
    "<!--MOCK:SENT; SUCCESS-->", 
    "<!--MOCK:SENT ; SUCCESS-->", 
    "<!--MOCK:SENT -->", 
    "<!-- MOCK:SENT-->", 
    "<!-- MOCK : SENT -->", 
    "<!-- MOCK: SENT -->", 
    "<!-- MOCK :SENT -->", 
};
foreach (var value in values)
{
    var match = regex.Match(value);
    Console.WriteLine($"Mode: [{match.Groups["mode"].Value}], Responses: [{match.Groups["responses"].Value}]");
}
```

Comment: Make the spaces : '\s*' .  The asterisks is zero or more occurrences.

Comment: Do your "mode" and "responses" groups always consist of capital letters, or can they contain other characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to use lookahead here. This is how I would do it:

`(?<mode>[A-Z]+)([ \-:]+(?<responses>[A-Z; ]+\b))?`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6xpkt1

Regarding the other answer that was posted, and the comment on your question, I completely disagree. `\s` is not the same as a literal space. It includes *all* whitespace characters, which can get you into trouble if you're only expecting spaces.

Comment: When I first checked the fiddle I thought it wasn't working correctly. Then I realized that the regex in the fiddle and this one didn't quite match. When I plugged in the one above it worked correctly. I updated your post to the new fiddle link for future visitors. Looks like I was overthinking it, this is much cleaner than the direction I was going with it. The only change I made was to change `[A-Z]` to `[A-Za-z]` in case the user enters lower case.

Comment: it's true that the `\s` can match a space or a tab character. But in almost cases we usually would like to match the tab char as well, so `\s` is really helpful and exactly what we need here. Even in this case the OP should use `\s`, I don't think he would accept any tab character as part of a group (mode or response). You seem to get what the OP wants fine but not dare to be sure that he would like to use something like `\s` instead of literal space in this case ( =)) funny enough).